# Are #include directives processed prior to macro expansion regardless of their location within a file?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I came across some code the other day that was similar to the following (the following has been over-simplified for the sake of brevity):

**config.h**

```
#ifndef __CONFIG__
#define __CONFIG__

#define DEVELOPMENT_BLD     _TRUE_

#if (DEVELOPMENT_BLD == _TRUE_)
    #define FILE_EXT ".dev"
#else
    #define FILE_EXT ".bin"
#endif

#define PROJECT_STRING  "my_project"
#define FILE_NAME       PROJECT_STRING FILE_EXT

/* Common include files */
#include "my_defs.h"

#endif /* __CONFIG__ */
```

**my_defs.h**

```
#ifndef __MY_DEFS__
#define __MY_DEFS__

#define _TRUE_      1

#endif /* __MY_DEFS__ */
```

The project had always compiled without any issues, but since I made some minor changes (and the actual project was rather large) I decided to run Lint on it.  When I did, I received the following error:

`Warning 553: Undefined preprocessor variable '_TRUE_', assumed 0`

I then wondered why the compiler didn't catch that `_TRUE_` is defined in my_defs.h which is included **after** the macro's first usage.  So I compiled it on a different compiler with the same results - succesful compilation, no warnings and `FILE_NAME` was correctly evaluated regardless of how I set `DEVELOPMENT_BLD` (using `_TRUE_` or `!_TRUE_`).  Here are my two compiler settings:

`ArmCC -c -cpu Cortex-M3 -g -O0 --apcs=interwork -I "..\ARM\CMSIS\Include" -I "..\ARM\INC\NXP\LPC17xx" -o "file.o" --omf_browse "file.crf" --depend "file.d" "file.c"`

`mingw32-gcc.exe -pedantic -Wall  -g     -c D:\dev\practice\header_question\main.c -o obj\Debug\main.o`

I decided to run a simple test to see if the value of `FILE_NAME` was being properly evaluated by the preprocessor.  I also wanted to see what the value of `DEVELOPMENT_BLD` actually was.  I ran the following code two times:

**main.c**

```
#include "config.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   printf("FILE_NAME:%s, WHAT_IS_TRUE:%d", FILE_NAME,DEVELOPMENT_BLD);
    return 0;
}
```

The first time I used the value `#define DEVELOPMENT_BLD _TRUE_` with this result:

`FILE_NAME:my_project.dev, WHAT_IS_TRUE:1`

The second time I used the value `#define DEVELOPMENT_BLD !_TRUE_` with this result:

`FILE_NAME:my_project.bin, WHAT_IS_TRUE:0`

My first thought was that perhaps `_TRUE_` was being defined elsewhere - so just to be sure I commented out `#include "my_defs.h"`.  I then began to receive a compiler error:

`error: '_TRUE_' undeclared (first use in this function)`

All of that leads to my question.  Are #include statements required to be evaluated by the preprocessor before macro expansion or did I just get lucky?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C pre-processor acts on directives as it encounters them.  In this context, the warning is correct; at the time you use `#if DEVELOPMENT_BUILD == _TRUE_`, the effective value of `_TRUE_` is zero. However, because of the `#define DEVELOPMENT_BUILD _TRUE_` definition, the preprocessor is evaluating `#if 0 == 0`, which is true.  However, you'd have had the same result if you'd specified `#define DEVELOPMENT_BUILD _FALSE_` because `_FALSE_` would also be implicitly 0 and hence the test would be `#if 0 == 0` again (which also evaluates to true).  If, when the preprocessor has finished evaluating expressions in the `#if` condition, there are identifiers left over, they are implicitly assumed to be 0.

Note that names starting with an underscore and a capital letter or another underscore are reserved for any use by the implementation.  You are treading on very thin ice with your choice of names such as `_TRUE_` and `__CONFIG__`.  (Just because system headers use names like that is not a good reason for you to do so — in fact, quite the opposite.  The system headers are carefully keeping out of the namespace reserved for you to use; you should keep out of the namespace reserved for the system.)

Comment: The Lint warning makes perfect sense to me.  However, I am curious as to why neither of the compilers provided any warnings.  Not only did they compile correctly, but they evaluated `_TRUE_` correctly as well.

Comment: Because there is nothing to warn about; the standard says "thou shalt interpret undefined identifiers (in preprocessor conditionals) as if they were defined as 0" so the compilers do that without complaint.

Comment: Of course, after your `my_defs.h` header is included, the meaning of `_TRUE_` changes, but the conditionals don't.  If `#if DEVELOPMENT_BUILD == _TRUE_` was encountered after `#include "my_defs.h"`, then it expands to `#if 1 == 1` (instead of `#if 0 == 0`), but the end result is still true.  The value of a macro is determined when it is used, not when it is defined (so the RHS of your initial `#define DEVELOPMENT_BUILD _TRUE_` remains `_TRUE_` until the macro `DEVELOPMENT_BUILD` is expanded, and `_TRUE_` then takes on its current value.

Comment: ...and that is why my output from the printf showed that `DEVELOPMENT_BUILD` was equal to 1... because from the perspective of main.c, `_TRUE_` had been defined.  That's what I was missing.  Thanks for your help.